# Is there a way to "link" a github repository using gcloud CLI

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, build, gcloud

I'm trying to automate the creation of Google Cloud projects and setup Google Cloud Build to automatically build a github repository.

But before creating the triggers with gcloud CLI, i have to "link" the remote github repository and I haven't find clues on how to do it.

If I don't do that, i have the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.builds.triggers.create.github) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Repository mapping does not exist. Please visit https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/triggers/connect?project=ID to connect a repository to your project
```

My github repositories use the Google Cloud Build github app to allow the cloud build integration.

Answer (score 0):

In [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers#build_trigger) regarding creating triggers there is a part with `gcloud beta`:

> **To create a trigger if your source code is in GitHub:**
>
> ````
>     gcloud beta builds triggers create github \
>     --repo-name=[REPO_NAME] \
>     --repo-owner=[REPO_OWNER] \
>     --branch-pattern=".*" \
>     --build-config=[BUILD_CONFIG_FILE] \ ```
> ````

Please check [gcloud reference](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/builds/triggers/create/github) for the command.

Comment: Yes, i saw that, but it give me the same error:
`ERROR: (gcloud.beta.builds.triggers.create.github) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Repository mapping does not exist. Please visit https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/triggers/connect?project=ID to connect a repository to your project`

Comment: Indeed linking itself is not possible outside of GUI. So automatization will be possible with Google Cloud Repositories. I suggest to report feature request https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/getting-support?hl=en_US#file_bugs_or_feature_requests